# Katoolin error on Ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: system-installation, kali, katoolin

I already install Katoolin Package on my Ubuntu like below:

[image]

But the problem is when I want to use & install some package of it (ex. wifi Package) the error happens like this:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

[image]

How can I fix that problem and use kali packages on ubuntu?

P.S: I did run `apt-get -f install` but an error happens again:

```
root@sky-Net:/home/sky-net# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libexo-common libexo-helpers libgarcon-common libkeybinder0 libvte-common
  libvte9 thunar-data xfdesktop4-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  locales
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1358 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,924 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,904 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 247658 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.19-18_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.19-18) over (2.13+git20120306-12.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-18_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-18_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: yes but an error happens again :

Comment: Run Katoolin again, select entry 1 and in the the next menu the entry to remove the Kali Repos. Then come back and I will repair your system.

Comment: ok . I've done that ... so what now?!  :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you miss the step to add Kali repositories and update before you go through install by categories. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VxCWVoZEEE) on how to install Kali tools on Ubuntu, which worked for me.